# Dynamically Declare Properties for a Typescript Interface

Tags: typescript

Is there a shorthand way to declare an interface with a lot of properties that follow a pattern. In my case I am creating a graph that will have 30 data points. My interface would be something like

```
interface BarData {
  day1: number;
  day2: number;
  ...
  day30: number;
}
```

Is there some notation that would allow me to declare `day*` ranging from 1 to 30 without having to write them all?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJqrrm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - OMG that is so cool. (I sound like a fanboi. But seriously, wow.)

Comment: @jcalz this is awesome! I think this is preferable to T.J's as it avoids having to list all the single numbers and is more dynamic for different ranges as I will have different timeframes than just 30 days. If you add this as an answer I'll accept. An explanation would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are already okay with using `BarData` but want a way to write it out with less boilerplate code (at the expense of more confusing code, unfortunately), here's one approach:

```
type LessThan<N extends number, A extends number[] = []> =
    N extends A['length'] ? A[number] : LessThan<N, [...A, A['length']]>;

type OneToThirty = Exclude<LessThan<31>, 0>;
/* type OneToThirty = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 
  | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 
  19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 */

interface BarData extends Record<`day${OneToThirty}`, number> { }
```

The `LessThan<N>` type function is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that takes a non-negative whole number [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `N` and produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all non-negative whole number literal types less than `N`.  So `LessThan<5>` is `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4`.  It achieves this by accumulating a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) consisting of the `length` property of the previous accumulator value.  So `[]` has a length of `0`, and `[0]` has a length of `1`, and `[0, 1]` has a length of `2`, etc.

So then we can use `LessThan<31>` to get all the numbers between `0` and `30`, and then use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to exclude `0` and get numbers from `1` to `30`.

After that we append those numbers to the string `"day"` via [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types), use [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to refer to a type with those `day*` keys and whose value types are `number`, and finally define `BarData` as an `interface` extending that record type.

You can ensure that it works:

```
function foo(bar: BarData) {
    bar.day14 = 3;
}
```

Hooray!

---

But... I am a bit skeptical that you really are okay with `BarData` though.  If you are programmatically describing key names at the type level, I suppose you want to programmatically create them at runtime also.  But the compiler doesn't know what `for (let i=1; i<31; i++) {}` will produce `i` of type `OneToThirty`.  It will just infer `number`.  And so you'll get errors:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
  bar[`day${i}`]++; // error!
  // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type  
  // '`day${number}`' can't be used to index type 'BarData'
}
```

Unless you start jumping through further hoops:

```
for (let j: OneToThirty = 1; j <= 30; j = j + 1 as OneToThirty) {
  bar[`day${j}`]++; // okay
}
```

which is fine but not any more type safe than just the alternative, where `BarData` has a [pattern index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) and you just take care to stay in bounds:

```
interface BarData {
  [k: `day${number}`]: number;
}
function foo(bar: BarData) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    bar[`day${i}`]++; // okay
  }
}
```

At which point you might as well just use an array, for all the good it's doing you:

```
interface BarData {
  day: number[];
}
function foo(bar: BarData) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    bar.day[i]++; // okay
  }
}
```

This is probably the most conventional approach.  Still, if you're happy with your original `BarData` definition, then the `OneToThirty` stuff at the top will achieve what you're looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKglgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIBCS4BElRLoDeAUOugCZICeAjAFzoQCuAtgEbwDc5VtAJiatOPPgDpJfajQDMABmHsucXgF8QwUtqg0ADhgAyMAM4mAKgAskEADwA5dDAAesCJRPNl8ADToAgk6uMO6eIioA2gC66AC86NEAfHF8ji5uHgERAOQANiEA5lCW2TEA-Fnh8DFMxmZWNg5+EZLi-n7+OfkQRSVRUYm8pLoG6ADyEDDmAPZWYHC6cegAos4ouSyUMLZ1FtZ2snSJfvKDpKDoIxgTU7OW84vxdOgAPugCr+iynwAsnwCsnwAbJ8AOyfAAc6D4bwAnJ86PIEc83nQPqjvqi-qjAaiQajwaioW8+HR4W8BEiKSj3uj3pj3tj3rj3vj3oT3sT3uSvkjNNpILBEKgMNg8AQiOkQpkAEowFDTOCUWwAAxkABJiDcZnMFjQ1Cq-FU4MliOg1NoECwICgoGBphB0AhptMABQcHBMMX4QgAShIfA9cHEMjof3isiGFGdcHQrvyUHQYCWdG4SfQtgj8jTYAA1Ln-WQKBQgxE1bRNWADVF82ngMAnHA4IqAIR8Cj1lb5NghRNgNh6XJgFBgKC5GjoayeGzobI2GjZS76DBcFBIFgmDAuPRwUwme2O6YIJejaHF9Cd7Llmia40GxdriDZRNcdAbmCUS7TJPuFwnjDZN6ErZHwFp8DGcYJugABWTDancDwTk8abQRmWYoUsqG5ugzxIJ48G6rohbtugpbXpq0HVrWF4NtMADWtCgdoYEQEgPYmHoIroAAkpQzgAMpgAUAYUIK8DIGgWA4D6RBFsWER0Uw5HEHeKpREooiqEx0bWraB5Oi67qelJ4p+iJxYQfGMB9imOZobyOb5sR54ljgZYasQVZqdRnb0Yx54WhQYGkMFrHsZxkn+E25licKklAYQ5kUDIGmRFEvBBeBul2g6BlukGXrSRKzkWYqkHWemyHppmDlJk5SXFkGIa0BEYA1rmda0QxNAkYF5raCFQA)

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of TypeScript you can do that with a union of the valid date suffixes and a [template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#handbook-content) type:

```typescript
type DayNumbers = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6; // ...and so on
type BarData = {
    [key in `day${DayNumbers}`]: number;
}
```

That requires that the object have all of the days:

```typescript
// Works, it has all the required properties
const example1: BarData = {
    day1: 1,
    day2: 2,
    day3: 3,
    day4: 4,
    day5: 5,
    day6: 6,
};

// Doesn't work, it's missing `day6`:
const example2: BarData = { // Error: Property 'day6' is missing in type ... but required in type 'BarData'.(2741)
    day1: 1,
    day2: 2,
    day3: 3,
    day4: 4,
    day5: 5,
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghiAcgVwLYCMICcDOUC8UAjFAD5QBMZUAzNQCzUCs1AbANxQD0XUAdALgA7ACZQcAeygShAKFCQoAIThZ4wOASgBvWVH1QA2gGsIIKAEshUAAYiEAEm3wkaTLgC+NgLoAuKEJu2OyyHrKyPFAA6hJYxjgANJbAUAAWcHhwADZZUMCp0FgQAI7IFkViYFgSkFjAFhA4sgDGMjgpEAAecKhgWRBE-ipqcBpaugZQ9iCDxAl6BtMU-hTzk9M0-jRriwj0-vQ7+tNM-kxHUwis-qzzHiERvDASjUIA5CkA7rHGSRbAbzwqAsOBwVgA5rZpqwbL4Wm0Ot1ev1lspVOpNIRtNxeABRLDVLD+AAK1VqoCgb2hb0sQJBYKEkKseXA0AEfCg6GQKSKpXKEDEzIU0Dewwxbz4AAoKAB2ehEACUC2OCFmRAuSxWGoQm1o2pA+ygh2VlxApyg51CISAA)

If you don't want to require all of them, you can use `?` to make them optional:

```typescript
type DayNumbers = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6; // ...and so on
type BarData = {
    [key in `day${DayNumbers}`]?: number;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
}
```

...in which case `example2` above would be fine.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghiAcgVwLYCMICcDOUC8UAjFAD5QBMZUAzNQCzUCs1AbANxQD0XUAdALgA7ACZQcAeygShAKFCQoAIThZ4wOASgBvWVH1QA2gGsIIKAEshUAAYiEAEm3wkaTLgC+NgLoB+AFxQQm7Y7LIesrI8UADqEljGOAA0lsBQABZweHAANjlQwOnQWBAAjsgWJWJgWBKQWMAWEDiyAMYyOGkQAB5wqGA5EESBKmpwGlq6BlD2IMPESXoGsxSBFIvTszSBNBvLCPSB9Hv6s0yBTCczCKyBrIseYVG8AII5klAA7vGJKYXQNTq2EazSgqmgdUaMlybQ6XV6-UGq2UqnUmkIU32c0CRCuKzWeIQ21ohJAhygxyWpwQ5ygl3CYSAA)